# Securely check if user is logged in on another domain (JSONP)

Tags: design-patterns, authentication, facebook, security

For the purpose of my question, say there's a web app and a site on different domains. A user can log into the web app, which keeps the user logged in throughout the session, or uses a cookie if the user wants to be remembered for 30 days. Very standard.

Now, from the site, I need to check if the user is logged into the web app (on a different domain). I obviously have no direct access to the browser's session or cookies for the web app. I believe my only option is to do a JSONP request from the site's JavaScript to a URL on the web app's domain. The web app then responds with either 1 or 0 depending on whether the user is logged in. Am I heading in the right direction? Either way, I can do a JSONP request and get the response without much difficulty.

While I have the 1 or 0 logged in value in the JavaScript, however, I need access to the value in the site's backend code (Ruby, PHP, whatever). Now we're really getting to the heart of my question. This value could be stored in a cookie by the JavaScript, but what's stopping a malicious user from just setting this cookie manually? How do I securely transfer this value from the JSONP response to my backend code?

A few final notes:

1. I can't do the request to the web app URL from the site's backend code (Ruby, PHP) because the user agent is the server, not the browser that the web app knows is logged in or not.
2. I believe Facebook Login/Connect works similar to this, but it's hard to understand all that's going on looking at the code. An explanation of the pattern (if it is a pattern) would be most helpful!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that occurs to me would be to have the web app return not just a 0 or 1, but some sort of encrypted token that could then be checked server-side on the other domain. It could be something pretty simple like md5('somethingsecret'.$userid) in addition to the logged-on state.  When your external site backend gets the cookie from its front-end javascript, just make the same md5 and compare the values to make sure no one has forged the userid.

Comment: I was thinking something similar. The site doesn't know the user ID, but it does know other values that could be hashed to provide a comparison key. I guess my insecurity is that I don't know if this is a common pattern that provides enough security. Any idea?

Comment: Your flow-path is a bit unusual, but the basic idea is pretty common. It's essentially the same as the way many websites set a login cookie for themselves, you are just doing it across two sites where one creates it and another validates it. As long as you have some info that is unique to each user, you can generate a simple token that cannot be duplicated by any other  user.

Comment: Can you explain what's unusual about it?

Comment: Well the fact that you are involving a second site in the process, as well as the use of JavaScript to set an "intermediate" cookie to facilitate the transfer between domains. Usually when checking login status, the server process receives a cookie directly from the browser's memory in one step; your server process is getting the same data, but with the extra client-side step of fetching and preparing the cookie before passing it to the server. It's like a recursive cookie fetch. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are approaching this from the wrong side of the fence. Instead of checking to see if the user is logged in via a cross-domain JSONP request (which opens an attack vector that is difficult to mitigate) why not make a server-to-server request between the two applications?

I am not sure what platform you are using, but any of them should be able to make an HTTP request to the other site and get a response about the user. Then you can lock down that app to only accept those requests from that server instead of allow them from any user that feels like asking.

Comment: Actually he addressed that in his notes. A connection from the server would not include the web app login cookie, so the web app could not respond appropriately. The request must come from the browser so that it can send the cookie. At least if I am understanding his setup correctly.

Comment: Why couldn't a request from the server include the the cookie? It is being sent to the server on the request, so it can be sent in the server-to-server request. Just because the user agent is the server does not mean it cannot send cookies.

Comment: Because the cookie that needs to be sent to the web app is not in the domain of the webpage. So the server page that would need to initiate the connection would never see the cookie. Again this is if I am understanding the setup correctly, I'll wait for the OP to comment further on this.

Comment: Ah, I follow now. I misunderstood which session cookie was being sent.